# Filter ResultSet after MongDB MapReduce

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

Consider the following MongoDB collection / prototype that keeps track of how many cookies a given person has at a given point in time:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c5b5c1865e463c5b6a5b748"),
  "person": "Drew",
  "cookies": 1,
  "timestamp": ISODate("2019-02-05T20:34:48.922Z")
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c5b5c2265e463c5b6a5b749"),
  "person": "Max",
  "cookies": 3,
  "timestamp": ISODate("2019-02-06T20:34:48.922Z")
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c5b5c2e65e463c5b6a5b74a"),
  "person": "Max",
  "cookies": 0,
  "timestamp": ISODate("2019-02-07T20:34:48.922Z")
}
```

Ultimately, I need to get all people who currently have more than 0 cookies - In the above example, only "Drew" would qualify - ("Max" had 3, but later only had 0).

I've written the following map / reduce functions to sort this out..

```
var map = function(){
  emit(this.person, {'timestamp' : this.timestamp, 'cookies': this.cookies})
}

var reduce = function(person, cookies){
  let latestCookie = cookies.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.timestamp > b.timestamp){
      return -1;
    } else if(a.timestamp < b.timestamp){
      return 1
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  })[0];

    return {
      'timestamp' : latestCookie.timestamp,
      'cookies'   : latestCookie.cookies
    };
}
```

This works fine and I get the following resultSet:

```
db.cookies.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out:{inline:1}})
...
"results": [
    {
      "_id": "Drew",
      "value": {
        "timestamp": ISODate("2019-02-05T20:34:48.922Z"),
        "cookies": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "Max",
      "value": {
        "timestamp": ISODate("2019-02-07T20:34:48.922Z"),
        "cookies": 0
      }
    }
  ],
  ...
```

Max is included in the results - But I'd like for him to not be included (he has 0 cookies after all)

What are my options here?  I'm still relatively new to MongoDB.  I have looked at `finalize` as well as creating a temporary collection (`{out: "temp.cookies"}`) but I'm just curious if there's an easier option or parameter I am overlooking.

Am I crazy for using MapReduce to solve this problem? The actual workload behind this scenario will include millions of rows..

Thanks in advance

Comment: well, i'm not sure, if you can just store the updated value of the cookie,if you can , then it will be a lot more easy and fast.